# Code for copy data within a range to notepad

Tags: excel, vba

I don't understand coding, I've tried but it just doesn't make sense to me.  Much respect to all who can learn and understand this complex other language.  If any of you can help, I'd be grateful.

I suspect this is a simple problem to solve...

I have a range of cells, A1:E30, in cells in columns B and C within this range data is entered using drop down lists, when certain data is entered into these cells information is automatically entered into columns A and E on the same row.  Not all cells within the range will contain data.

What I'd like is a command button that when pressed will copy only the cells within this range that contain text and then paste that text into notepad, without any blank lines and keeping corresponding cells next to each other.

I can do the very basic:

```
Range("A1:E30").Copy
Shell"notepad.exe",VbNormalFocus
Sendkeys"^V"
```

The code copies the entire range, but this includes empty lines.

Is there a way to do what I need?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the lines that are empty are within the data block, you can sort prior to copying.  If the blank lines are at the end, you can find the last row of data prior to copying and only copy the data.

```
LastRow=Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Row
Range("A1:E" & LastRow).Copy
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but I'm getting an error message "Compile error: Syntax error".  Also, the blank lines could be within the data block, and/or at the end.  Could the code to sort the data be linked to the button press?

Comment: Thank you again, but this is copying all cells in the range and pasting it with the spaces.  Isn't there a way to copy only the cells with text in them, then paste them to notepad without any blank spaces between the rows?

Comment: Then sort them first.  Google `Range.Sort` and you will get the Microsoft method for sorting.